# How to get nested array output using the DoctrineObject Hydrator in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, doctrine, hal-json

***Is it possible* / *How* to make the ZF2 [`DoctrineObject` hydrator](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Stdlib/Hydrator/DoctrineObject.php) provide its output as a nested array instead of an array with nested entity objects?**

So, that

```
Array
(
    [id] => 123,
    [title] => FooTitle,
    [bar] => Array
    (
        [id] => 567,
        [title] => BarTitle
    )
)
```

instead of that

```
Array
(
    [id] => 123,
    [title] => FooTitle,
    [bar] => Bar Object
    (
        [id] => 567,
        [title] => BarTitle
    )
)
```

---

Additional informaition / background:

In a ZF2 application I'm working on I'm using Doctrine and have entities `Foo` and `Bar`. There is a `OneToOne` relationship between them -- `Foo` `has a` `Bar`:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "title": "FooTitle",
    "bar": {
        "id": "567",
        "title": "BarTitle"
    }
}
```

When I retrieve a `Foo` object and pass it to the `DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator#extract(...)` (in my application it's done within the `ZF\Hal\Plugin#convertEntityToArray(...)`), I get an array with element `bar` of the type `Bar`.

In the next step (actually several calls later) this result is passed to the `Zend\View\Renderer\JsonRenderer#render(...)` and then to the `Zend\Json\Json::encode(...)`, that internally performs the [`json_encode(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php).

So the value of the `foo[bar]` gets filtered out and the output looks like:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "title": "FooTitle",
    "bar": {}
}
```

Comment: Can't you just make your entities implement `Zend\Stdlib\JsonSerializable` and then the `JsonRenderer` will utilise your provided `jsonSerialize()` functions?

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Yes, its possible and would work (just tested). Another solution would be to extend the `DoctrineObject` hydrator and make there the object elements to arrays. But actually I was sure, that it's just about the configs of the `DoctrineObject` and I just cannot find the proper setting. Doesn't the `DoctrineObject` provides this functionality?

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with Doctrine, but I think you're correct in thinking the `DoctrineObject` should already provide this functionality, but only if you've provided strategies to how sub-objects should be hydrated / extracted. If it doesn't have an associated strategy it will just return the object. See [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Stdlib/Hydrator/DoctrineObject.php#L171) and [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stdlib/blob/master/src/Hydrator/AbstractHydrator.php#L124)

Answer (score 0):

The DoctrineObject Hydrator's purpose is to hydrate objects from arrays or extract object to arrays. If you do not want to generate an object, you should use ArraySerializable hydrator available in the Zend framework.